# Typeorm transformer always return true

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I'm using typeorm and trying to transform a column in the database to bollean instead of string.

The field in the bank is bit.

But I want to return as boolean, but when using or transforming it always returns true, what to do?

```
    export default class ColumnBooleanTransformer implements ValueTransformer {
      public from(value?: string | null): boolean | undefined {
        return Boolean(Number(value));
      }
    
      public to(value?: boolean | null): string | undefined {
        return value ? '1' : '0';
      }
```

My column:

```
  @Column({
    nullable: false,
    transformer: new ColumnBooleanTransformer(),
  })
  STAProvado: boolean;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, add type property to column, use the same type created in the bank

```
 @Column({
    type: 'bit',
    nullable: false,
    transformer: new ColumnBooleanTransformer(),
  })
  isAdmin: boolean;
```